# ArraySegment is throwing System.ArgumentException for apparently no good reason

Tags: c#, arrays

Pretty simple code snippet:

```
using System.Text;

byte[] byteArray = new byte[256];
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    byteArray[i] = (byte)i;
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(byteArray, 167, 170);
```

but compiled using .NET 6.0, I get an unhandled exception error when I call the `ArraySegment` constructor. Why? Clearly `byteArray` has 256 elements. The sub array from indices 167-170 should not be out of bounds.

Comment: The sub array from indices sub array from indices 167-337 is clearly out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN documents

```
public ArraySegment (T[] array, int offset, int count);
```

That means that your array segments

```
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(byteArray, 167, 170);
```

Is equivalent to

```
var span = byteArray[167..(167 + 170)];
```

Which is equivalent to

```
var span = byteArray[167...337];
```

Which is clearly out of range.

I think you wanted

```
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(byteArray, 167, 3);
```

Comment: indeed I did want that!